# set-cookie header is getting blocked on React app running locally from Laravel app running on different domain

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel APP deployed on Vapor(AWS Lambda). I am trying to send an API request to it from a React app running locally.

Below are the set-cookie headers from the API response.

```
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlVSZGJrT2duOEo4dzFkaHNsb1pIS3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaXdlQmo2QmtsVjByUnFkREt1UE5XYWIvQTc1b3pVZlFLL09rWDhEY1FIL3JiYUg1Z2lBZUdQeVp1MEhyay80RG00SHJZNytSN1paZ0VKNjBBSzQxOEF6Y2tGSGF5SHZpa3QrbkVQWjErKzMzeXFJaUwrUTBqVi9iTklaRnBROXQiLCJtYWMiOiIzNTgxOGFiZGRkZTRlYTE5MzY1MDY4Y2UzMzA5YzdkYzk5NWUxMzdjMDdkMTY4NDI5YmFiNGQ4NTg4NGIzNTQxIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=; expires=Fri, 17-Sep-2021 16:00:35 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost; samesite=lax
```

```
hylo_session=eyJpdiI6InEzK0Q3aytCWGM2T1dVSFdTSy80L2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYUpwd2tKV09GbTMrc2Z1WUdoM0hSc1V4TGFDQjR4elNxeFJudGpMMWM0M2kyUzZlY3JnNzRRc3BvRWk0S1J2S1RwOFRrSndzcFI2Vjh0c1Ewd1JiM1E5bHhXRDBkbnlLRlI4czdqTUsrRXViZXRHcUV2NklOekQvYk5iSWpraUQiLCJtYWMiOiI1OGExZGFiNzdkNzVlY2U3MjFkZGJjMTNjYTE3ZmVhYWQ4MjM5NzZkMDkxNWRkZDQ2Mjk4YTlhYTYzMTdlOGQ0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0=; expires=Fri, 17-Sep-2021 16:00:35 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost; httponly; samesite=lax
```

Somehow the cookie is blocked. I am getting the following warning in the Network Tab:

```
The attempt to set cookie via set-cookie is blocked because its domain attribute is invalid with regards to the current host URL.
```

I am using Laravel Sanctum for Auth. Following are my env related to session:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000
```

I even tried setting same_site value to none in sesison.php but it is still sending samesite as lax.

Any clue how to get this working?

Comment: What is the "current host URL"?

Comment: The API URL is https://sparkling-sea-42fefnd5hyoe.vapor-farm-e1.com. I am sending request from http://localhost:3000

Comment: Why is it trying to set a cookie for `domain=localhost` then? `sparkling-sea-42fefnd5hyoe.vapor-farm-e1.com` can set a cookie for `sparkling-sea-42fefnd5hyoe.vapor-farm-e1.com`, and not just any other arbitrary host name.

Comment: I tried setting the domain to the API domain but it was still not working. So tried setting it to localhost.

Comment: Now you're probably dealing with CORS issues then?

Comment: The issue is cross-domain cookies are getting blocked. The backend and front end are on different domains.

Comment: And are you specifying that you want to send & accept credentials with your client-side calls?

Comment: Yes. I am using Axios on client-side and I have set credentials to true.